# C# WebClient running slow the first time

Tags: performance, string, c#-4.0, download, webclient

I'm using WebClient to download some text from a web-page, like this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string str = wc.DownloadString("http://blah");
```

Now while it works absolutely fine, one problem I am facing with it is that the first time it initializes and downloads the string it's very slow - it takes approximately 5 seconds. After that it downloads the text within half a second.

Is there any way I could overcome this problem? I would really like it to be fast all the time so that it isn't annoying for the user.

I'm using C#.NET 4.0 if that matters.

Comment: Is the remote site you are trying to fetch ASP.NET?

Comment: I would do some performance profiling to see whether it is the remote part that takes 5 seconds until it responds or the local part.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem and my remote site is ASP.Net. Why do you ask if it's ASP.Net Darin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution was taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/3d9c4c15-348c-4293-875b-f3d03e01f760)

What you are seeing is caused by automatic proxy discovery. When the app starts, Initially
we dicsover what proxy to use and then use that proxy or the proxy script for the
subsequent requests. When you close the app, the script or the proxy infrastructure is gone
and we have to do this again next time the app starts up.

You have a couple of choices.

1. You can turn off the automatic proxy by going into the IE settings and switching off the automatically detect proxy settings option.  This is in Tools->Internet Options->Connections tab->LAN Settings button.  Uncheck the Automatically detect settings.
2. if You can determine a static proxy server [trhat does not change dynamically its name] you can specify that proxy
   WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(,......);

WebClient.Proxy = wp;

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a similar problem but I couldn't find one anywhere. I had actually 'fixed' the problem by running an extra request on application load, but that is obviously a bad idea.